# Adding PYTHONPATH to .zprofile/.bash_profile

Tags: python, linux, bash, zsh, pythonpath

I need to add the contents of a directory called Python with many folders in it containing python scripts to my PYTHONPATH in zsh to allow them to be imported. So far I am planning on using a for loop to iterate through the directories and add the script paths to the PYTHONPATH like so:

```
for dir in /Users/will/Python/*
```

do

...

done

if [ -f ~/.zprofile ]; then
source ~/.zprofile
fi

Im not sure what to do next or if this is in any way correct and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
DIRS=(/Users/will/Python/**) # Store all the subdirectories in this variable
export PYTHONPATH=${(j<:>)DIRS}:$PYTHONPATH  # prepend those subdirectories to PYTHONPATH
```

To know more about the prepend syntax see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796371/manipulate-zsh-arrays-with-operator-j)